# Implementation of Matrix<T>: std::vector<T> vs std::unique_ptr<T[]>?

Tags: c++, matrix

As part of a hobby project, I needed a rectangular Matrix object to maintain state of a grid. At first, the implementation seemed trivial and unworthy of further discussion: (I haven't included all the code, only the relevant code)

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
    uint64_t rows, columns;
    std::vector<T> _data;

    uint64_t get_flat_index(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {
        return row * columns + column;
    }

public:
    Matrix(uint64_t rows, uint64_t columns) :
    rows(rows), columns(columns), _data(rows * columns, {}) {}

    //Auto-generated by compiler
    //Matrix(Matrix const&) = default;
    //Matrix(Matrix &&) = default;
    //Matrix & operator=(Matrix const&) = default;
    //Matrix & operator=(Matrix &&) = default;
    //~Matrix() = default;

    T & operator()(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) {
        return _data[get_flat_index(row, column)];
    }

    T const& operator()(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {
        return _data[get_flat_index(row, column)];
    }

    bool is_valid(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {
        return row < rows && column < columns;
    }

    T & at(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) {
        if(!is_valid(row, column)) throw std::runtime_error("row/column out of bounds!");
        return operator()(row, column);
    }

    T const& at(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {
        if(!is_valid(row, column)) throw std::runtime_error("row/column out of bounds!");
        return operator()(row, column);
    }

    uint64_t get_rows() const {return rows;}
    uint64_t get_columns() const {return columns;}

    void resize(uint64_t new_rows, uint64_t new_columns) {
        if (new_rows == rows && new_columns == columns) return;

        if (new_columns == columns) {
            _data.resize(new_rows * new_columns, {});
        }
        else {
            std::vector<T> new_data(new_rows * new_columns, {});
            for (uint64_t row = 0; row < std::min(rows, new_rows); row++) {
                auto beginning_of_row = _data.begin() + (row * columns);
                auto ending_of_row = beginning_of_row + std::min(columns, new_columns);
                auto beginning_of_new_row = new_data.begin() + (row * new_columns);
                std::copy(beginning_of_row, ending_of_row, beginning_of_new_row);
            }
            _data = std::move(new_data);
        }

        columns = new_columns;
        rows = new_rows;
    }

    //Other code, not related to this post
};
```

So it all seems pretty great right? I can write stuff like `Matrix<int> m(50,50);`, `m(5, 10) = 17;`, `try {m.at(52, 47) = 99;} catch (std::runtime_error const& e) {std::cerr << "Whoops!" << std::endl;}`, and it all just works, right?

Well, it turns out there's at least one situation where the code misbehaves in a major way:

```
Matrix<bool> is_tested(60, 60); 
is_tested(30, 40) = true; //Does not compile! Whoops.
```

Yeah. Turns out that because [`std::vector<bool>` has been specialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), it messes with the integrity of my code.

My initial solution was to write a specialization for `Matrix<bool>`.

```
template<>
class Matrix<bool> {
    uint64_t rows, columns;
    std::unique_ptr<bool[]> _data;

    //Duplicated: 
    uint64_t get_flat_index(uint64_t rows, uint64_t columns) {/*...*/}
public:
    Matrix(uint64_t rows, uint64_t columns) :
    rows(rows), columns(columns), _data(std::make_unique<bool[]>(rows * columns)) {}

    //I don't get this for free anymore!
    Matrix(Matrix const& m) : Matrix(m.rows, m.columns) {
        std::copy(m._data.get(), m._data.get() + rows * columns, _data.get());
    }

    //I have to include this manually now.
    Matrix(Matrix &&) = default;

    //More duplicated code...
    bool & operator()(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) {/*...*/}
    bool const& operator()(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {/*...*/}
    bool is_valid(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {/*...*/}
    bool & at(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) {/*...*/}
    bool const& at(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {/*...*/}
    uint64_t get_rows() const {/*...*/}
    uint64_t get_columns() const {/*...*/}

    void resize(uint64_t new_rows, uint64_t new_columns) {
        if (new_rows == rows && new_columns == columns) return;

        std::unique_ptr<bool[]> new_data{ std::make_unique<bool[]>(new_rows * new_columns) };

        if (new_columns == columns) {
            std::copy(
                begin(),
                begin() + ((new_rows < rows) ? new_rows * new_columns : rows * new_columns),
                new_data.get()
            );
        }
        else {
            for (uint64_t row = 0; row < std::min(rows, new_rows); row++) {
                auto beginning_of_row = _data.get() + (row * columns);
                auto ending_of_row = beginning_of_row + std::min(columns, new_columns);
                auto beginning_of_new_row = new_data.get() + (row * new_columns);
                std::copy(beginning_of_row, ending_of_row, beginning_of_new_row);
            }
        }

        _data = std::move(new_data);
        columns = new_columns;
        rows = new_rows;
    }

    //All the other code needs to be duplicated as well!
};
```

This is, of course, frustrating, not least of which since every time I spot a mistake in one version of the code, I have to fix it in the other, and same goes if I redesign something.

So my next thought was to ditch `std::vector<T>` entirely, and just specialize around `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. This solves the code duplication problem, but it means I can't take advantage of any optimization potential that `std::vector<T>` offers over `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, like smart use of allocators and other benefits, all to ensure that `Matrix<bool>` works correctly. I tried a version that partitions out the divergent code into a superclass called `_matrix_impl<T>` that specializes around `bool` itself, leaving `Matrix<T>` to not have to specialize anything itself, but there was still a significant amount of code duplication on things like the variable declarations and the `get_flat_index` code (not to mention a lot of the code not listed here being duplicated) and it created its own nightmare for code maintainability, vis-a-vis inheritance of template superclasses.

So ultimately, my question is: what is the best solution for this situation? Since my code doesn't have things like `insert`, `emplace`, or other similar constructs, does it make sense to just use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` for everything, since many of the benefits I'd otherwise have access to are moot anyways? If I use `std::vector<T>`instead, is there a way to gracefully handle `Matrix<bool>` without dealing with the headache that is `std::vector<bool>`? Is there a superior third/fourth option I haven't even considered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since my code doesn't have things like `insert`, `emplace`, or other similar constructs, does it make sense to just use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` for everything, since many of the benefits I'd otherwise have access to are moot anyways?

It's not a bad idea from a performance standpoint; given that you matrix is fixed-size, you can get away with just one pointer instead of three, so your matrix objects are going to be slightly lighter weight than when using `std::vector` as a data backend; also, given that that pointer has now way to be modified outside the constructor, the compiler may be able to be extra smart and avoid re-reading it from your object when performing manipulations intermixed with extern function calls (it's a common cause of slight slowdown with `std::vector`).

OTOH, you are not getting the copy/assignment stuff for free, if this is important it's for you to judge.

> If I use `std::vector<T>` instead, is there a way to gracefully handle `Matrix<bool>` without dealing with the headache that is `std::vector<bool>`?

A possibility that I actually used is to use the `std::vector<T>::reference` `typedef`s for your accessors, thus forwarding whatever proxy object `std::vector<bool>` likes to use straight to your user. So, something like:

```
typedef std::vector<T>::reference reference;
typedef std::vector<T>::const_reference const_reference;

reference operator()(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) {
    return _data[get_flat_index(row, column)];
}

const_reference operator()(uint64_t row, uint64_t column) const {
    return _data[get_flat_index(row, column)];
}

// ... same with at & co. ...
```

Incidentally, if you are to implement your `Matrix` class using `std::vector` as a backend, you can avoid storing the number of rows - the `std::vector` already stores the full size, so the height is just one division away (but as usual, check if the size reduction of the `Matrix` object is worth the extra cost of the division by profiling the code against common scenarios).